# CSS Selectors outside parent div

Tags: html, css

So I have a bit of HTML where I have a navigation bar hidden off-screen until the checkbox at the top is :checked by clicking the label (hamburger png) at which point it comes back on screen until such a time as the hamburger icon is clicked again and the navigation menu is hidden off screen once more.

Now if I were to stick the nav section inside the header I could use the selectors (+ and ~) to target it...but I can't think of a way to do that when it's a new div that's not immediately next to the checkbox and in it's own div outside of the parent. The only parent they would have in common then is #wrapper, no? But I can't figure out how to target that from inside another div.

Is there a way to target this in pure CSS to make the nav menu pop out when the checkbox is :checked and back when it is un-checked? I already have the JavaScript for it, but I wanted it in CSS as well in case, well, you know...the user has JavaScript disabled.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <a href="#" id="logo">TitleBar</a>
    <label for="hamburger" id="nav_open_icon"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vv4Rdc9.png" alt="open-menu"></label>
    <label for="hamburger" id="nav_close_icon"><img src="/img/hamburger/close.png" alt="close-menu"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li id="#"><a href="#">Home</a><img src="/img/home.png" alt="Home"></li>
      <li id="#"><a href="#">Stuff</a><img src="/img/about.png" alt="About"></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    body{
       color: white;
       background-color: black;
       font-family: "PT Sans", "sans-serif";
       font-size: 1rem;
    }

    #container{
       margin: 0 auto;
       min-width: 320px;
       max-width: 1600px;
    }

    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
       color:#FEBC11;
       text-align: center;
    }

    header{
       padding: 1rem 0rem 1rem 0rem;
       background-color: #333;
    }

    #logo{
       color:#FEBC11;
       font-size: 1rem;
       text-decoration: none;
       margin-left: .5rem;
       font-weight: bold;
    }

    #nav_open_icon{
       position: absolute;
       top: 1rem;
       right: 0;
       margin-right: 1rem;
       width: 30px;
       height: 23px;
    }

    #nav_close_icon{
       display: none;
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
       top: 0.6rem;
       width: 30px;
       height: 30px;
       margin-right: 1rem;
    }

    #hamburger{
       /*display: none;*/
    }

    #overlay{

    }

    nav{
       position: absolute;
       left: -50%;
       background-color:rgba(124,115,115,.2);
       width: 10rem;
    }

    .nav_toggle{  
       position: absolute;
       left: 0%;
       background-color:rgba(51,51,51,1); 
      }

   #hamburger:checked nav + nav_toggle{

 }

    nav ul{
       list-style-type: none;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;  
    }

    nav li{
       padding: 1.1rem;   
    }

    nav a{
       color: white;
       text-decoration: none;
       margin-left: 1rem;  
    }

    nav img{
       float: left;
       margin: -.5rem 0rem 0rem -.2rem;
       height: 35px;
       width: 35px;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zaL594s8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot target the `nav` from the checkbox with css, because it is outside of the `header` that contains the checkbox. Is there any reason you can't move the nav inside the `header` and do something like:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zaL594s8/4/)

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  background-color: rgba(124, 115, 115, .2);
  width: 10rem;
  transition: .3s;
}

input:checked + nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
}
```

Comment: There's really no reason I can't, no. I just liked it set up the way I had it more and wanted to see if that was an option. I couldn't find a way so I assumed it wasn't...but hey...thought I'd ask :D Perhaps someone will stumble on this if they have the same question. Thanks for the response...I will move it into the header :)